# App not supported in Android Market for x-large tablets

Tags: android

I am creating an application only for tablets (7 and 10.1 inch). I put below the code in my android manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"      
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:smallScreens="false"  
                      android:normalScreens="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

I put my app in Android market.
But it's not showing up in my Samsung Galaxy tab 10.1. In that support device is only 7 inch Tablets. I want my app for both 7 inch and 10.1 inch.  Please, some one help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Check this link carefully http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should add API Level 9.

```
<manifest ... >
...
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
<application ... >
    ...
<application>

 </manifest>
```

and

Note: Android 2.3 (API Level 9) introduced a new attribute for the  element: xlargeScreens, shown below. It works the same as the other screen attributes above, but, if neither your minSdkVersion or targetSdkVersion are set to "9", the default value is "false" when your application is installed on a device running Android 2.3.

when targetSdkVersion is 9 or higher
android:xlargeScreens -> **Whether or not the application UI is designed for use on xlarge screens — "true" if it is, and "false" if not.   "false" "true"**

http://android.ankara-gtug.org/guide/practices/screens_support.html#attrs

Comment: it's means i give minSdkverdion= 9 ?? than it's not run in Galaxy Tab 7 na?

Plz reply this

Comment: ya,As per my knowledge It's not run in Galaxy Tab 7.

Comment: Try this <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="9"/>