# Android App not showing in Google Android Market for Tablets

Tags: android, permissions, google-play, tablet

my app shows in Android Market for well over 600 different mobile phones. And currently has about 100 thousand users. So, it's fairly popular, but for a longest time I am unable to figure out why my app is not showing for tablet users of Android Market. Due to this problem, I am missing all tablet users and big chunk of the market.

I've got to know about this issue from my clients, so just to test it, I've tried to access Android Market from 3 different types of tablets myself, but failed on all of them. My app is simply not showing for tablets, just for the phones.

In my app's manifest file, I have only following 3 required permissions:

Rest of the permissions my app requires are marked as **android:required="false"** in the manifest file:
    
    
    
Etc...

I am somewhat puzzled as to why Google doesn't want to show my app in Android Market to their tablet users, but shows it just fine to all phone users.

As far as SDK, I require minimum Android 2.2:  
So that should be fine.

Anyways, I am missing entire tablet market and don't know where I am making a mistake.

BTW. I've tried to compile RUN my app on my own tablet at home without any issues, so it really just comes down to Google not showing it to tablet users. I know app works on tablets just fine.

This is my entire manifest, any clue as to what is causing the issue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="name.xml"
    android:versionCode="24"
    android:versionName="3.4" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:required="false" ></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:required="false" ></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" android:required="false" ></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" android:required="false" ></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" android:required="false" ></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" android:required="false" ></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" android:required="false" ></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false" ></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" android:required="false" ></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" android:required="false" ></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" android:required="false" ></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" android:required="false"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" android:required="false" ></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" android:required="false" ></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name="name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH_LONG_PRESS" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: i thought tablets only run 3.0 code?

Comment: I require minimum 2.2, all newer versions are supported automatically. Plus I know app works fine on tablets, I was able to install it from apk file without any issues.

Comment: Probably a misconfiguration in your Manifest that is causing it to show as not compatible for Tablets, do you use screen size, density tags in your manifest?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884896/app-not-supported-in-android-market-for-x-large-tablets

Comment: I've attached entire Manifest to my original post. Any clues?

Comment: I have the following permissions in the manifest. Will my app show up for tablets? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/985de509ae8d68d72bf3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem lies in your `<uses-permission..>` declaration for permissions you don't need. It does not take `android:required="false"` attribute and enables them most likely. Permissions themselves shouldn't (in most cases) filter out your application though but Market can assign required features based on them.

Comment: Are you saying, that I should remove all instances of permissions where it says: android:required="false"? 
Not sure I understand, can you contemplate on this a little more?

Comment: All I can say documentation does not state uses-permission is conditional and provides only attribute ``android:name``. And I find it quite likely your application asks for all permissions you've listed - including the ones with ``required="false"``. Which in return might add some HW feature filter, for example, automatically by Android Market.

Comment: Ah I see. So that's interesting. I will test that and report back. I wonder if that's the culprit behind all my problems. Anyways, it's still somewhat puzzling as to why on phones it would work fine, but not on tablets. Just doesn't make sense to treat those two platforms differently in terms of designing XML file.

Comment: My guess would be TELEPHONY feature (but I'm not exactly familiar with tablets though). Here's link to list on how permissions imply feature requirements, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions-features .

Comment: Ok, I just got to it, but I fail to understand, how should I specify this line for example: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:required="false" ></uses-permission>, if I am not to use 'uses-permission', it seems to be a required tag.

Comment: If you don't need bluetooth permission, remove it altogether. If you want to make it conditional, introduce uses-feature tag which you set required="false". This way your application won't be filtered out by Market but expects you handle devices not supporting bluetooth on code level.

Comment: In my application I prefer if user had a Bluetooth permission enabled, because there is a functionality which relates to Bluetooth. But I'd like people to install my app, even if they do not have a Bluetooth, that is why I am making it conditional already by adding: required="false", so they can use it without Bluetooth. Anyways, if I remove it completely, what is the purpose of required="false"? I fail to understand this somehow.

Comment: ``<uses-permission..>`` does not have ``required="true/false"`` attribute (at least in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html)). And I find it very unlikely adding it made any difference. Also, leave the permission in place if your application uses bluetooth of course - and according to documentation it would be best to add related ``<uses-feature..>`` in place too.

Comment: I've added uses-feature today (based on documentation) and will see if it helps and my app shows in the market on my tablet. I'll let you know tomorrow.

Comment: uses-feature fixed the problem, thanks for pointing me out in the proper direction

Comment: Hey, I have these following permissions, will my app show up in tablets?https://gist.github.com/anonymous/985de509ae8d68d72bf3

Answer (score 1):

Are you using <supports-screens> tag. Problem is not in your code but the Manifest file.

Comment: I am not using <supports-screens> tag, please see my entire Manifest attached to original post.

Comment: Should I add something like this? To make it work?
    <supports-screens android:resizeable=["true"| "false"]
                  android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"]
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="integer"
                  android:compatibleWidthLimitDp="integer"
                  android:largestWidthLimitDp="integer"/>

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"/>
```

to your manifest.